# onLoad return 0 as width and height

Tags: javascript, image, preloader

I'm trying to build a simple image preload which creates an image element and stores it so I can later instantly use it.

I've setup this fairly simple singleton class which I can use everywhere:

```
var Preloader = (function() {
var instance = null;

function PrivateConstructor() {
    var total = 0;
    var onComplete = null;

    this.loadImages = function(images, completeHandler) {
        total = images.length;
        onComplete = completeHandler;

        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onLoad = this.onLoad(img);
            img.src = images[i];
        }
    }

    this.onLoad = function(img) {
        console.log(img);
        console.log(img.width);
        console.log(img.height)
        total--;

        if(total == 0) onComplete();
    }
}

return new function() {
    this.getInstance = function() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new PrivateConstructor();
            instance.constructor = null;
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
})()
```

Now when I use this and check my width and height, it remains 0

```
Preloader.getInstance().loadImages(['https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/188302352/nasalogo_twitter_bigger.jpg'], function() {
    console.log('images loaded');
});

// output
<img src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/188302352/nasalogo_twitter_bigger.jpg">
0
0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
img.onLoad = this.onLoad(img);
```

you are incorrectly calling `this.onLoad` immediately, rather than passing that function as the load handler.  Your code thus completes without ever waiting for the images to be actually loaded.

You also have the case wrong - the handler property should be called `img.onload` rather than `img.onLoad`.

Note that the `.onload` event handler will be called with the image as its `this` context variable rather than having it passed as a parameter, so you would use `this` (representing the image, not your class) inside that event handler.

The alternative would be to write:

```
var self = this;
img.onload = function() {
    self.onLoad(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, was looking at this code quite a while and couldn't see the obvious anymore. Now it's returning the width and the height perfectly!